# Plugin Facebook - PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, apache-cordova

estou utilizando um plugin do PhoneGap para logar-se com o Facebook, está funcionando perfeitamente, eu consigo obter o email e o id do usuario, agora, eu precisava colocar esses dados num JSON para eu trabalhar com ele via ajax.

segue o codigo:

**HTML**

```
        <div class="event listening button" onclick="login();">Logar com Facebook</div>
        <div class="event listening button" onclick="apiTest();">Mostrar Dados</div>
        <div class="event listening button" onclick="logout();">Fazer Logout</div>
```

**JS**

```
        var login = function () {
          if (!window.cordova) {
             var appId = '305528339609022';
             facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(appId);
          }
          facebookConnectPlugin.login( ["email"], 
             function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
             function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
        }

        var apiTest = function () { 
            facebookConnectPlugin.api( "me/?fields=id,email", ["user_birthday"],
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) }); 
        }

        var logout = function () { 
            facebookConnectPlugin.logout( 
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
        }
```

podem ver que faço o `login()` depois clico no *mostrar dados*, nisso vai aparecer um alert pra mim mostrando os dados. Agora, eu precisava botar ele num array, para pegar via ajax...

vocês podem ver no ar

http://www.petfy.com.br/facebookconnect/www/

**CERTO AGORA EU PEGUEI OS DADOS, ELE ESTA EM OBJETO**

**MEU OBJETO**

```
                var apiTest = function () { 
                facebookConnectPlugin.api( "me/?fields=id,email", ["user_birthday"],
                    function (response) { 
                      dados = response;
                    });
            }
```

o objeto chama-se "dados", como eu posso pegar esse objeto e fazer um `json_enconde()`?

Comment: botar num array para pegar via ajax ? xDD

Comment: na apiTest(), a response que recebes já é um js object, basta guardares numa var qlqer

Comment: @EnoqueDuarte como ficaria? var id = JSON.stringify(response); ?

Comment: podes declarar a var 1º no topo, onde quisers (var dados), e depois entao dentro da função dás o valor (dados = response),,,,, se queres um object não fazes o stringify xd, o stringify é para transformar o jobject numa string json

Comment: vou meter o codigo numa resposta para veres

Comment: @EnoqueDuarte eu entendi, agora, como faço para por exmplo, pegar ela via ajax?

vou editar a pergunta

Comment: o que queres dizer como pegar ela via ajax ? a variavel está definida, é só usa-la :)

Comment: uhm ? esse codigo vai tar no servidor ?? estás a usar node.js ?

Comment: acho que te estás a confundir xd, o javascript corre client-side

Comment: sim @EnoqueDuarte eu quis dizer que o codigo que conecta com o facebook vai estar no server-side, para eu pegar esses dados no server eu vo ta no cliente-side! entende?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16255/discussion-between-enoque-duarte-and-furlan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bastante simples, defines uma variavel fora da chamada à api e dentro da chamada guardas a `response` nessa variavel... como queres um objeto, não fazes o `JSON.stringify()` , o stringify serve apenas para respresentar o objeto numa string json (para apresentar num alert como ai tens por exemplo)

```
   var dados;  

   var login = function () {
      if (!window.cordova) {
         var appId = '305528339609022';
         facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(appId);
      }
      facebookConnectPlugin.login( ["email"], 
         function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
         function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
    }

    var apiTest = function () { 
        facebookConnectPlugin.api( "me/?fields=id,email", ["user_birthday"],
            function (response) { 
              dados = response;
              alert("sucesso !!!"+JSON.stringify(response));
            },
            function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) }); 
    }

    var logout = function () { 
        facebookConnectPlugin.logout( 
            function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
            function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
    }
```

Comment: Olá, bem vindo SO-PT, sua resposta parece ser boa e responder a pergunta, só que não é há muita explicação em torno dela, se possível, comente a sua solução proposta para que possamos entender melhor o que ela propõe.